# Multiple commands produce flutter GoogleUtilities

Tags: ios, flutter, build, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to build for app store. using command `flutter build ipa` and getting below error. Although the build works (when I run from Android studio)on debug mode and I can receive push notification.

```
warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework GoogleUtilities'. Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to
resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

warning: Multiple targets match implicit dependency for linker flags '-framework GoogleUtilities'.Consider adding an explicit dependency on the intended target to
resolve this ambiguity. (in target 'ImageNotification' from project 'Runner')
error: Multiple commands produce

'/Users/manu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-csuwafuzvneucvdjlkobmosdwxae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuild
FilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output
'/Users/manu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-csuwafuzvneucvdjlkobmosdwxae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuild
FilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' has create directory command with output
'/Users/manu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-csuwafuzvneucvdjlkobmosdwxae/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuild
FilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

I added a `ImageNotification` new target Notification Service extension for push image in push notifications

Here is my pod file :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.3'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), _FILE_)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(_FILE_))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

Answer (score 34):

ADD - pod 'GoogleUtilities' to ImageNotification target and Runner target in PodFile.

```
target 'ImageNotification' do
  ...
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end

target 'Runner' do
  ...
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
end
```

then delete the PodFile.lock then run flutter clean, then flutter pub get, then flutter build ios.
After that open the ios module in Xcode and build archive.
it will work.

Comment: sadly wasnt working for me, but it gave me an idea where to search further --> within the podfile

Comment: Did not help me either

Comment: works as charm! thanks

Comment: Don't forget to specify platform :ios as at least 10.0 or above in order to work

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4583

Answer (score 2):

After trying number of efforts it build and archive successfully. I never know which settings are applicable, but few steps are as followed, let check with your settings.

In **Podfile**,

```
target 'Runner' do
 pod 'GoogleUtilities'
 use_frameworks!
 #use_modular_headers!
 
 flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 #pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'GoogleUtilities'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Run flutter build,

```
flutter build ios --release --verbose
```

As followed with [FCM via APNs Integration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images),

Follow Step 1 to 4.

In Xcode Project,
Targets > Runner > Build Phases > Move Sequence

- 'Embed App Extensions' then
- '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks then
- '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'

And Mark Checked(✅) 'Copy only when installing' in 'Embed App Extensions'

That's it try archive now,

Select 'Runner' > Any iOS Device

And

Product > Archive

Done!!

And not forgot to follow the [Notification Payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image) request for FCM,

```
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        'mutable-content': 1
      }
    },
    fcm_options: {
      image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
```

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

> Comment the pod line:

```
target 'ImageNotification' do
  use_frameworks!
  #pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

> Comment FirebaseMessaging import and Extension Helper line in didReceiveNotificationRequest

```
#import "NotificationService.h"
//#import "FirebaseMessaging.h"
@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler)(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent *bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * _Nonnull))contentHandler {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
    self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];
    
//    [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent withContentHandler:contentHandler];
}

- (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

@end
```

**And this worked for me!!**

Comment: So you basically just disabled Firebase/Messaging in your project? That's exactly what I try to install.

Answer (score 0):

just remove 'use modular headers!' from podfile